# Insert large amount of data to DB using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

When inserting large amount of data my application ran out of memory, I've tried 2 ways of solving the issue:

1). Use hibernate batching as described here - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

2). Doing batch commit:

```
split data into batches;
for each batch{
  session.beginTxn();
  persist();
  session.commitTxn()
}
```

I tested the solutions, and the memory saved was the same.

`Question:` Does this result look right to you? And what's happening behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is not the right tool to insert large amounts of data, use a stored procedure instead.

If you like, you can call your stored procedure through hibernate easily.