# inserting large amount of data

Tags: java, mysql, bigdata

I am reading a 468migs file, segregating data and then have to store into mysql. I am using  Eclipse-Kepler, mysql 5.0+ 
The file has more than 5 million lines. Using mappedbytebuffer I am reading file which has drastically brought down 12 hours of time to 4 mins. :)

The hash table I am inserting has size of 851362, it took me 5.6 hours to insert data. 
I am running a batch of 15000 insert queries at a time. Using a prepared statement.

I cannot load the file in mysql using LOADFILE, as the file is highly unorganized and needs to be organized, removed the duplicates and fit into my work.

I need help at this point, because, I have to insert this much of thrice in database and thus totaling to >10-12 hours.
Would using Hibernate a good option?

[Insert large amount of data to DB using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220952/insert-large-amount-of-data-to-db-using-hibernate)

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Hibernate might help, but I never heard of using hibernate to go faster.  Unusually the first suggestion to making a hibernate system go faster is don't use hibernate.

Comment: You can *always* use `LOAD DATA INFILE`, but you may have to go through a lot of trouble to generate the right structure to import. yes, organizing is annoying, but if your data isn't organized, how can you expect this import to be faster?

Comment: @ peter lawrey - so how do we proceed? Spring batch? Would you suggest that?
@ tadman - the organized data is stored in hash table in less than 4 mins, but the bottleneck here is insertion.

Comment: Gentle bounce, experts kindly suggest.

Comment: Should srping batch be used???
Please guide